# Scrapy - Buscar itens em formulario

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

sou bem iniciante no assunto, será que conseguem me ajudar? estou testando spiders para buscar licitações.
Porém não consigo retornar os itens pelo formulário.
[image]

tenho o código abaixo de exemplo:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class AmparoDeSaoFranciscoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AMPARO_DE_SAO_FRANCISCO'
    start_urls = ['https://amparodosaofrancisco.se.gov.br/portaltransparencia/?servico=cidadao/publicacaolicitacao/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response,
                                               formdata={'ctl00$body$hfAnoLicitacoes': '2020' ,'ctl00$body$hfMesLicitacoes': '04'},
                                               callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        orgao = response.xpath('//*[@id="dataTables-Licitacoes"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').get()
        processo = response.xpath('//*[@id="dataTables-Licitacoes"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').get()
        modalidade = response.xpath('//*[@id="dataTables-Licitacoes"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').get()
        autorizacao = response.xpath('//*[@id="dataTables-Licitacoes"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]').get()
        objeto = response.xpath('//*[@id="dataTables-Licitacoes"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]').get()
        yield {
            'orgao': orgao,
            'processp': processo,
            'modalidade': modalidade,
            'autorizacao': autorizacao,
            'objeto': objeto,
        }
```

isso não esta me retornando nenhum valor.
setei os valores: 2020 e 04 no formulario, mas o ideal serial já puxar todos os anos e meses.
conseguem me dar uma luz?
abs!

Comment: O link está quebrado.